# What type of verb follow "convenience"?

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

What types of verb should follow "convenience" in the following example?

`It's for the convenience of those people who love hockey to play`

`It's for the convenience of those people who love hockey playing`

Which one would be correct? Or if they're both acceptable, what is the actual difference behind them?

Comment: Neither of the sentences make sense. What are you actually trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-spelled the word "convenience". I edited it. @Catija

Comment: I still don't understand how efficient playing makes it more convenient. Grammatically, "to play" is the correct option but the sentence doesn't mean anything.

Comment: people who *love* hockey, not people who *loves* hockey

Comment: "Convenience" is a noun, and pretty much any verb can follow it.

Comment: @Edward There's still one more: "Love hockey to play" is probably wrong, since that sentence construction makes the noun hockey a grammatical agent, performing the act of playing, which it logically can not do. I think you mean to say "love to play hockey".

Comment: @Tonepoet It's for the convenience of "those people who love hockey" to play, or in other words, it's for the convenience of those people that love hockey to play, or even more specific, it's for the convenience of those hockey lovers to play

Answer (score 2):

The correct wording is:

> It's for the convenience of those people who love to play hockey

Presumably "it" refers to something hockey players can buy/do to make their lives easier?

Answer (score 0):

I would add [another possible variant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) to D.Nelson's answer.

> - It's for the convenience of those people who love playing hockey.